# Как сослаться на значение url?

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Есть url  `site.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/myvalue`.

Как сослаться на значение `myvalue`, отталкиваясь из того, что оно последнее либо 4-е в роутинге?

Answer (score 1):

1. Разбить explode по /. Если последнее, то взять последний элемент массива (используя end()).
2. Если Вы знаете, каким должно быть значение (например, значение, myvalue - это число, а все остальные - нет), то можно для массива, который получен после explode, сделать `array_map("intval", $mas)`, а затем найти то, которое не 0.
3. Если вы знаете, каким примерно может быть значение myvalue, то для поиска по массиву можно использовать `preg_grep`.
4. Если вы точно знаете, каким будет myvalue, то можно просто сделать `array_search` от массива из п.1.

Comment: Для более безопасного метода лучше через .htaccess разбирать строку. И дальше обрабатывать GET переменные.

Comment: @terantul

> Для более безопасного метода лучше через .htaccess разбирать строку. И дальше обрабатывать GET переменные.

Серьезно?

Comment: через регулярные выражения всё, что не разрешено, не пройдёт

Comment: @terantul окей, почему эти регулярки не осуществить на бэке и какое отношение это имеет к безопасности?